# Restream m3u8 with python, ffmpeg or nginx

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I need to restream m3u8 videos to my service. The project is written in django. I can't get my m3u8 with ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -hide_banner -i https://link/stream.m3u8 -c copy -f flv rtmp:127.0.0.1/live/stream
```

Please tell me how do I do this?

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -hide_banner -i https://link/stream.m3u8 -c copy -f flv rtmp:127.0.0.1/live/stream
```